# Adsense shows own site in iframe

Tags: iframe, adsense

we have 2 ads on our main page that are sometimes displayed right and sometimes they just show the main page inside the iframe for the ad.
Did i do anything wrong? is there someone who got the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

> sometimes displayed right and sometimes they just show the main page
>   inside the iframe for the ad. Did i do anything wrong?

It sounds like you did, but check "[Backup ads](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/113262?hl=en)" settings for those units and if you see "main page" URL in "Show other ads from another URL" field - then yes, that is wrong.

In that field you can enter the URL of one special dedicated **page** (for example `http://www.example.com/ads/our-shop.php`) where you have nothing but ad code from *another network*, or *your own* "ad code" (for example `<a href="http://www.example.com/shop.php" alt="Buy something from us!" target="_top"><img src="http://www.example.com/img/shop.jpg" width="728" height="90" /></a>`)

(That ad code: a) should be the only content of that ("special") page and b) it should be exact `width x height` match of the parent AdSense ad, and c) it can't be AdSense code, and d) you should use "absolute" URLs and `target="_top"` for links.)

Also, that is obviously not the only issue, and you should probably analyze your site and page and try to find out [**why** the ad serving is falling back to "Backup"](https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/2473099?hl=en#ts=2473046,2473112,2473050,2473059,2473263,2473266) and why no AdSense ad is available for that page. AdSense inventory is huge, and that normally shouldn't happen, so there is a chance that [something is wrong on your site, or page](http://adsense.blogspot.com/2010/02/troubleshooting-tips-part-iib-ad.html).